# Spring autowire byType vs constructor ( xml configuration)

Tags: spring

I have a query. About "Spring autowire byType vs constructor ( xml configuration)".

Read at multiple places that constructor autowire injection is similar to byType. But while I am testing, In case of ambiguity, constructor autowire behaves like **byName** (even not exactly), need your input if I am missing any important point.

I have below configuration:

```
<bean name="customerRepository" class="repository.HibernameCustomerRepositoryImpl"/>
<bean name="customerRepository1" class="repository.EclipselinkCustomerRepositoryImpl"/>
<bean name="customerService" class="service.CustomerServiceImpl" autowire="..."/>
```

**byType output :** org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException [Good Expected output]

**constuctor output:** pankaj [Notice I am not getting NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException and it gives me output for customerRepository why? below is sample code] 
[Seems In case of ambiguity it does check for property name and choose bean whose name matching with property name]

**Sample code:**

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

public CustomerServiceImpl() {

}

public CustomerServiceImpl(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
}

//  public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
//  this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
//  }

@Override
public List<customer> findAll() {
return customerRepository.findAll();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring does autowire by name, but not exactly like it does with the "byName" autowire mode.

The [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-autowire) states :

> Autowiring by property name. Spring looks for a bean with the same name as the property that needs to be autowired. For example, if a bean definition is set to autowire by name and it contains a master property (that is, it has a setMaster(..) method), Spring looks for a bean definition named master and uses it to set the property.

So, in order to autowire by name the setter method should be present. However, in this case the container matches the bean definition name with the name of the constructor argument to autowire in case of ambiguity.

**Example:**

Motor.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public interface Motor 
{
    public void start();
}
```

ElectricMotor1.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public class ElectricMotor1 implements Motor
{
    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Motor 1 Started.");
    }
}
```

ElectricMotor2.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public class ElectricMotor2 implements Motor
{
    public void start()
    {
        System.out.println("Motor 2 Started.");
    }
}
```

TeslaModelX.java

```
package com.chiranth;
public class TeslaModelX 
{
    private Motor motor;

    public TeslaModelX(Motor electricMotor1)
    {
        motor=electricMotor1;
    }

    public void goForward()
    {
        motor.start();
        System.out.println("Going Forward.");
    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="electricMotor1" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor1"/>
    <bean id="electricMotor2" class="com.chiranth.ElectricMotor2"/>

    <bean id="modelX" class="com.chiranth.TeslaModelX" autowire="constructor"/>
</beans>
```

Test.java

```
package com.chiranth;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring.xml");
        TeslaModelX modelX=(TeslaModelX)context.getBean("modelX");
        modelX.goForward();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Motor 1 Started.
Going Forward.
```

Even though the property name doesn't match the bean name in the above example, autowiring is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, when there is a ambiguos situation, Spring does Autowiring by Name. You can use `@Qualifier` to help Spring chose the right implementation based on name.
Check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)